# How delete suspended app from google play developer console?

Tags: android, google-play, suspend

I have app uploaded to google play store, but application has suspended from the Google Play Store due to some **violation of the impersonation or deceptive behavior provisions of the Content Policy**. In google console I am able see as below screenshots[image]

[image]

Now my question is how to remove this project from developer console? I don't want to see suspended application in my developer console.

Comment: no chance to delete your app until google change there policy. Just solved problem and re-submit your app. this is best practices.

Comment: if we publish the same app with correct policy is this suspended app will removed?

Comment: I have the same issue. I have sent a request to Google to add filtering for suspended (as well as unpublished) apps. Maybe if everyone who experience this issue sent them a request also, it might happen one day.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can only remove published apps. If it's suspended, it will just stay there until you fix it. You can't even hide it. Google should at least offer an option to "hide" suspended apps.

Comment: You cannot remove published apps either.

Comment: You can remove published app https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-remove-an-app-from-an-Android-developer-console

Comment: In my case, there haven't any option to fix suspended apps. If I don't fix the suspended app, will there be any problem?

Answer (score 12):

Official answer from google play team:

"For auditing purposes, we are unable to remove applications that have been suspended due to policy violations.

Unfortunately, package IDs for app files are unique and permanent; they cannot be deleted or re-used in the future. While you will be unable to upload the same package ID again, you will be able to upload a slight variation on the original package ID.

If your account is still in good standing and the nature of your app allows for republishing, you may release a new, policy-compliant version of your app under a different package ID."

Comment: Only those who the skin in the game know how oppressive and arbitrary this process can be. While Apple walked towards the light and made the app approval process light, fast and transparent, Google, in turn, walked into darkness. In the last week I had the App published and approved by Apple, all the push certificates configured now I can't solve suspension from Google, because my app only exists because COVID-19 desease, and according Google my app violates the terms because my App contains "COVID-19" in metadata. All SO needs developers and his treatment is totally one-sided and abusive

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, if the app was published before there is no way to delete it. Never. Only unpublished apps can be deleted.

Comment: before publish app on store, application suspended. That mean app not yet published.

Comment: You had never published it before?

Answer (score 5):

Google will not allow you to remove the suspended app. Make sure that your next apps maintain google app Policy Requirement. There may be chance of suspending your google app publish account too.